# Get "API key is missing" error when querying account details to Mailchimp API 3.0 using RestSharp

Tags: mailchimp, restsharp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When using RestSharp to query account details in your MailChimp account I get a "401: unauthorized" with "API key is missing", even though it clearly isn't!

We're using the same method to create our RestClient with several different methods, and in all requests it is working flawlessly. However, when we're trying to request the account details, meaning the RestRequest URI is empty, we get this weird error and message.

Examples:

```
private static RestClient CreateApi3Client(string apikey)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(null, apiKey);

    return client;
}

public void TestCases() {
    var client = CreateApi3Client(_account.MailChimpApiKey);

    var req1 = new RestRequest($"lists/{_account.MailChimpList}/webhooks", Method.GET); 
    var res1 = client.Execute(req1); // works perfectly 

    var req2 = new RestRequest($"automations/{account.MailChimpTriggerEmail}/emails", Method.GET); 
    var res2 = client.Execute(req2); // no problem

    var req3 = new RestRequest(Method.GET); 
    var res3 = client.Execute(req3); // will give 401, api key missing

    var req4 = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.GET); 
    var res4 = client.Execute(req4); // same here, 401
}
```

When trying the api call in Postman all is well. `https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0`, GET with basic auth gives me all the account information and when debugging in c# all looks identical.

I'm trying to decide whether to point blame to a bug in either RestSharp or MailChimp API. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours we finally found what was causing this..

When RestSharp is making the request to `https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/` it's opting to omit the trailing '/' 
(even if you specifically add this in the RestRequest, like: `new RestRequest("/", Method.GET)`)

so the request was made to `https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0`

This caused a serverside redirect to '`https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/`' (**with** the trailing '/') and for some reason this redirect scrubbed away the authentication header.

So we tried making a

`new RestRequest("/", Method.GET)`

with some parameters (`req.AddParameter("fields", "email")`) to make it not scrub the trailing '/', but this to was failing.

The only way we were able to "fool" RestSharp was to write it a bit less sexy like:

`new RestRequest("/?fields=email", Method.GET)`